# C# WebBrowser Error Thread

Tags: c#, browser, sta

I am having trouble getting a web browser in my form to work. When I run, I get this error ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.

It takes me to the form designer.cs file to this text this.webBrowser2 = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser(); and I really do not know what to do to get thebrowser working.

I have tried both MTAThread and STAThread in the Program.cs file cant seem to get it to work.

Thanks

Comment: did you try it on the method that's calling the new WebBrowser() control?

Answer (score 2):

You need to mark your thread as an `STAThread`, because COM controls require that apartment state.

There are two easy ways to do this:

- Mark your thread entry point (the function that your thread begins with) with the `[STAThread]` attribute. If you don't set it on the entry point but on some other method down the call stack, then this attribute won't be applied.
- If you are starting the thread using the System.Threading.Thread class, then set the apartment state of the thread to an `STAThread` using `Thread.SetApartmentState()`

Comment: It is already an STAThread, I still can't seem to get it working

Comment: Are you sure? What does `Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState()` return?

Comment: nevermind found the problem I accidentally created a new thread in another class.